# Windows 10 Licensing using Embedded 8/8.1 Key

Tags: windows, windows-10, license, windows-activation

I've asked this question at Microsoft Answers, TechNet, had two chat sessions with MS support, and been on the phone with "Pro" support for an hour and a half. At the end of the "Pro" support I was told that this is totally fine, but I asked for documentation to be emailed to me and never got it.

First off, this is in a commercial environment. We are imaging Dell laptops and desktops with Windows 10. The systems came with Windows 8/8.1 keys embedded, but were downgraded to 7. We are not "upgrading" from within the OS, just imaging right over the top.

After the imaging process Windows 10 automatically activates, I'm assuming because it sees the embedded 8/8.1 key.

Is this a properly/legitimately licensed copy of Windows 10?

If it is, how can we know? If it is not, why is Microsoft allowing this to happen?

Comment: "why is Microsoft allowing this to happen?" Never look a gift horse in the mouth

Comment: You appear to have created multiple accounts, which is why you cannot comment, and why your edits must be approved. Please read this Help document to learn how to get these accounts merged: https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft hasn't yet closed all the paths for a free upgrade to Windows 10.

It seems like you have discovered a new one. If it works and Windows 10 is
truly activated, than you are all set and the computer will have its digital
entitlement from now on registered with Microsoft.

It's unknown how long Microsoft will keep this door open.
However, as long as it works, this is completely legal and irrevocable, as
Microsoft only keeps track of your digital entitlement, not how you got it.

Comment: Harrymc, if possible could you expand on the topic of how Microsoft only keeps track of the digital entitlement, and not how it was acquired? In a commercial situation we are sort of hesitant/wary of what's happening here. On the one hand it would save a bunch of money in licensing cost. On the other hand, Windows is activating without us inputting a key, and there's no (obvious) official word from MS concerning this behavior. If audited we don't want any problems.

Comment: The info is a bit vague. See for example  [Activation in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12440/windows-10-activation): "A digital license (called a digital entitlement in Windows 10, Version 1511) is a method of activation in Windows 10 that doesn't require you to enter a product key. If you upgraded to Windows 10 for free from an activated copy of Windows 7 or Windows 8.1, you should have a digital license instead of a product key.". See also the section "Checking activation status". So it seems if you have a digital license you seem OK. But I can't guarantee anything.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I've seen that page now a few times, and you are right that it is very vague. I agree that, in general, it does seem to say that everything's OK when it says it says that Windows is activated with a Digital License. The two things that stick for me is where it says "upgraded to Windows 10 from and activated copy of Windows 7 or 8.1." Does that mean the Windows 10 installation was actually started from within the activated OS? Because we are just imaging over the top of the activated OS.

Comment: And second, is there an actual definition of a "Digital License?" Would the embedded key be considered the Digital License?

Comment: The Digital License is a fingerprint of the computer's hardware configuration, which will forever identify this computer before the Microsoft activation servers. Small changes are allowed, and the fingerprint will be updated, but large changes will require manual activation by Microsoft Support. There are articles that detail what it's made of, for example [this one](https://www.pcsteps.com/4484-how-windows-activation-works/), and the activation method is not part of it. I don't know what records Microsoft holds, but I never heard of a successful activation being contested by Microsoft.